Can work dir in Catalina Tomcat be outside of CATALINA_BASE?
I have tomcat9 running for a spring boot java app.
I have setup my CATALINA_BASE to a location /opt/something
For some writing restriction, I would like to have the work dir in a different location /var/run/work
I have tried
ln -Fs $CATALINA_BASE/work /var/run/work
It starts, but in my staging environment I’m getting lots of 404s, so the apps are not getting proper configured.
Any ideas if there are configurations to be changed as well or if this is not a possible approach?
Any other ideas to tackle the problem are appreciated.
